# how to test if array pointer is at first element in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

In a for loop it is simple...

```
for ( $idx = 0 ; $idx < count ( $array ) ; $idx ++ )
{
    if ( $idx == 0 )
    {
        // This is the first element of the array.
    }
}
```

How the hell is this done in a foreach loop?

is there a function like `is_first()` or something?

I'm looking for something like:

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
{
    if ( /* is the first element */ )
    {
        // do logic on first element
    }
    else
    {
        // all other logic
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could set a bool like `$is_first = true;` and then as soon as the loops been iterated once, set the bool to false.

But php has a lot of pre-built functions and id rather use that... or another way...

The whole bool way seem almost like... cheeting :s

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem with cheating? ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using "current()"

```
$myArray = array('a', 'b', 'c');
if (current($myArray) == $myArray[0]) {
    // We are at the first element
}
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Ways of retrieving the first element:

```
$myArray[0]

$slice = array_slice($myArray, 0, 1); 
$elm = array_pop($slice);
```

Comment: As long as its not an associative array, or it's an indexed with first key of 0

Comment: I modified my initial post that provides a way for fetching the first element for other kinds of arrays.

Comment: It not work. 
'foreach()' not move pointer of array. current() not show actual loop value.

Answer (score 24):

I usually do this :

```
$isFirst = true;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if($isFirst){
    //Do first stuff
  }else{
    //Do other stuff
  }
  $isFirst = false;
}
```

Works with any type of array, obviously.

Comment: If you put the `$isFirst = false;` inside the first `if` it will skip setting the variable at every loop.

Answer (score 7):

```
$myArray = array('a' => 'first', 'b' => 'second', 'c' => 'third'); 

reset($myArray);
$firstKey = key($myArray);
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === $firstKey) {
        echo "I'm Spartacus" , PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $key , " => " , $value , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use counter instead bool

```
$i = 0;

foreach ( $array as $key => $value )

    if ($i == 0) {
        // first
    } else  {
        // last
    }
    // …
    $i++;
}
```

or extract the first element by

```
$first = array_shift($array);
```

and `foreach` over the remain array;

Comment: Using array_shift and foreach over the remaining array seems the cleanest solution, providing you are not using the array after looping through it. Otherwise you want to pop the first element back on with array_unshift.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the operation on first element before the *foreach* loop, remove the element and then enter the *foreach* loop for the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = array_shift($idx);

foreach($idx as $key => $value){
...
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that will detect if an array key is first or last.

If no key is provided it will assume the current pointer position.

In a foreach loop you will need to provide the key since the pointer will not be correct.

```
public static function isFirst($array, $key=null)
{
    if($key===null){
      $key = key($array);
    }
    reset($array);
    $first = key($array);
    return $first === $key;
}

public static function isLast($array, $key=null)
{
    if($key===null){
        $key = key($array);
    }
    end($array);
    $last = key($array);
    return $last === $key;
}
```